# Show one item at a time in a listView in flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollview

I have a list of photos and want that one photo should be shown at a time. By this I mean if a user scrolls down then the upper photo should not be seen only the new one should be seen. It should not be like you can hold the scroll between two images. I want something like instagram reels where one reel is visible at a time.

**CODE:-**

```
              ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: postList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index)
                  {
                    return postList[index];
                  },
                );
```

Comment: use pageView to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using a [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) widget, or you could also use some plugin like [tiktoklikescroller](https://pub.dev/packages/tiktoklikescroller)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Physics Property of Listview. use this

```
physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
```

Answer (score 0):

its your listView

```
ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: postList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index)
              {
                return postList[index];
              },
            );
```

You can use pageView with Scroll direction vertical,

```
postList(){
return PageView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       itemBuilder: yourPageItems...,
       itemCount: listItemCount,

}
```